# Enforcing function parameter type to match returned object key with inference

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a object with multiple functions as seen below. I want that for each function the `eventKey` param is enforced to be a key of returned events of the same function. I don't understand why the below implementation does not work.

```
interface Channel<EKey extends string> {
  channel: string
  events: Record<EKey, string>
  eventKey: EKey
}

type ChannelFn = <EKey extends string>(id: string, eventKey: EKey) => Channel<EKey>

export const channels = {
  chat: (chatId, eventKey) => ({
    channel: `chat-${chatId}`,
    events: {
      foo: "foo",
      bar: "bar",
    },
    eventKey,
  }),
} satisfies Record<string, ChannelFn>
```